# How to limit the maximum CPU resources for a specific process?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, task-manager

I've googled and found [this blog](https://www.technorms.com/46600/regulate-cpu-usage-in-windows-10) but when I try to repeat the steps, I see that my context menu doesn't have the options to limit a process. I restarted Task Manager as admin but it didn't make any difference.

How can I limit Windows Defender? It goes bananas on occasion. I want it to keep working but not make my computer fan act as a helicopter...

[image: windows-1]

Comment: Have you tried the other programs mentioned in that blog?

Comment: Try the "details" tab of task manager. They moved things around a bit for win10 I believe

Comment: See also https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12322-how-to-avoid-high-cpu-usage-caused-by-the-msmpengexe-process